# R dummyvars - dummy variables for a single column

Tags: r, r-caret, dummy-variable

I'm trying to convert a bunch of transactions to a wide matrix to run some regression model with.

```
Trans_id     item_id
  123         ABC
  123         DEF
  123         XYZ
  345         ABC
  ...         ...
```

I'd like to convert to something like this:

```
Trans_id     item_ABC    item_DEF   item_XYZ   
  123            1           1          1
  345            1           0          0
```

I'm trying to do this using the dummyVars function in caret but can't get it to do what I need.

```
dv1 <- dummyVars(Trans_id ~ item_id , data = res1)
df2 <- predict(dv1, res1)
```

just gets me a list of item_id with no dummy matrix.

```
 item_id
   ABC
   DEF
   XYZ
   ABC
   ...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's not really dummy variable. It's a cross table of the two columns. `table(res1)` should give what you need.

Comment: In R there's `model.matrix(~.-1, data=x)`, but your categorical vars need to be of type `factor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are using `data.table`, then the `dcast` can be used

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data), Trans_id ~ paste0("item_", item_id), length)
#   Trans_id item_ABC item_DEF item_XYZ
#1:      123        1        1        1
#2:      345        1        0        0
```

Or a more general approach would be

```
dcast(setDT(data), Trans_id ~ paste0("item_", item_id), function(x) as.integer(length(x)>0))
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Trans_id = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 345L), item_id = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("ABC", "DEF", "XYZ"), class = "factor")),
 .Names = c("Trans_id", 
"item_id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `data.table`:

```
# load the data
data = read.table(
  text = 
"
Trans_id     item_id
  123         ABC
  123         DEF
  123         XYZ
  345         ABC
",
  header = TRUE
);

# load data table
library(data.table);

# make a data table
dt = setDT(x = data)[
  ,
  # make a count column for each item in each group
  .(
    item_ABC = length(x = which(x = item_id == "ABC")),
    item_DEF = length(x = which(x = item_id == "DEF")),
    item_XYZ = length(x = which(x = item_id == "XYZ"))
  ),
  # grouping by Trans_id
  by = Trans_id
];

# display the new table
dt;

       Trans_id item_ABC item_DEF item_XYZ
1:      123        1        1        1
2:      345        1        0        0
```

I hope this can help!

Answer (score 1):

You are making a very small mistake.
use the predict command like:

```
df2 <- predict(dv1, newdata = res1)
View(df2)
```

This should work.